# Google Sheets BUG: QUERY() doesn't work on a datarange with many columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have this query function:

```
=Query(DataIn!A:LK,"SELECT A,B")
```

And the output of the query in the first cell is this:

```
_id 82b60875-11ce-4acf-a6b1-39ed92e5b319 863f5f22-e9ee-4a08-9af2-c7fab2c72891 335dbba5-d6d2-415e-8fca-48bb52f1e8c3 fa2e7cd0-73e2-446d-8038-f5a30ac3ea80 c031aebe-1e3d-4bca-bf91-6d25fe30925b 86f97e07-bde2-4b89-99e3-aed4258a385f 90d07684-31ca-43fb-a59e-6a2c877b8f2f 5d5abba4-4d30-41b2-940d-753e3cc42c7a e113d82d-3584-43bc-91ae-a94abe456da2
```

I am 100% sure that only '_id' should be there. This only occurs when there is a large datarange, such as `A:LK`. If I shorten the datarange to `A:CA` (for example), then the output in the first cell is indeed:

```
_id
```

This is an annoying bug. How can I make Google make it go away?

==== EDIT ====

Here is a link to a reproduction of the bug. I think I've scrubbed any data that shouldn't be shown. If you see something that I have missed, please let me know:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15qASa-N-T_a9FPrdwE3-N6nMu6cUtZ-Rx20pQ-l73tU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have sample file with this bug? I've tested query with big table and [it's ok](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RoF0D4NNJC2F0KYsbRtkcESGv5rmGbUtLnOipGSc6bE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @MaxMakhrov, I have just created a sample file of the bug - in the question

Comment: I also first tried through populating a sheet with dummy data and it didn't work. Possibly related to having blank cells, or "-" in one of the columns, or something else

Comment: defining headers might help: `=Query(DataIn!A:LK,"SELECT A,B",1)`

Comment: ah. Thanks @MaxMakhrov. that did indeed work. wonder why it detects automatically for smaller ranges but not larger ranges

Comment: Why do you pass a very large range when you only want that the result include a couple of columns? Why do not use `=QUERY(DataIn!A:B,,)` instead of `=Query(DataIn!A:LK,"SELECT A,B")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, I've found some explanation on why query acts like this. If you don't enter the third parameter into query, then sheets try to detect the number of header rows automatically.  I discovered that:

1. It does not depend on number of columns in query
2. It seems to look only at last column.

Here's is example with data:

[image]

And this is what `=Query(DataIn!A:D,"SELECT A,B")` does:

[image]

If you paste any number in cell D2, then you'll have proper query result. Please [test it yourself](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jSn65PP8AmWyWZE5cwHolw_4vaqm3Y78RF-CN5jUU1s/edit?usp=sharing) and tell me if I missed something.

---

**Suggested solution**

Define number of headers in formula:

```
=Query(DataIn!A:D,"SELECT A,B", 1)
```

Comment: Yes, it seems if the last column in the query has an empty cell directly below the headers then the result is strange as described above. in which case you need to specify column headers. good catch